# Usage of "nonetheless" and "nevertheless"

Tags: synonyms, discourse-markers

Person A: "Is it just because you think I am sad, that you want to talk with me?"

Person B: "No, I want to talk with you ***_*__*_*___**."

In the blank, which word is correct: "nonetheless" or "nevertheless"? Also, can you give an example of the usage?

Comment: Nontheless, nevertheless and regardless all have a connotation that they are overcoming an objection or disregarding a reason for not doing something. E.g. "I'm busy" -> "I want to talk to you regardless" (I am disregarding for the fact you are busy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct word to use in this situation is *nonetheless*, although it sounds somewhat awkward to my ear:

> I want to talk to you nonetheless.

A more idiomatic alternative would be to use the word *regardless*:

> I want to talk to you regardless.

I don't believe that *nevertheless* is idiomatic here. *Nevertheless* is usually used as a clause-initial adverb, and doesn't fall naturally at the end of a sentence.

> Nevertheless, I want to talk to you.

Comment: yes, the reagardless sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

More common usage in British English would be:

No, I want to talk to you *anyway*.