# Difference between nevertheless and nonetheless

Tags: differences, synonyms, discourse-markers

I am never quite sure whether to use nevertheless or nonetheless; they seem almost synonymous to me, but I think I might be missing a subtle distinction. Is there a difference, and if so, how do I determine which is right in different circumstances?

I am specifically thinking of sentences such as these:

> - I am busy Saturday; **nevertheless** I will come to your party anyway.
> - I am busy Saturday; **nonetheless** I will come to your party anyway.

There is a question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/usage-of-nonetheless-and-nevertheless) that deals with a specific idiomatic usage, but I was thinking of the general type of usage, as given in the party example above.

Comment: I always thought of "Nevertheless" as being a way of saying that not only is whatever-it-is not lessened now, but that it will at no point ever be lessened, no matter what might come to pass. How far am I off my rocker?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The regular MW dictionary entry for [nonetheless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonetheless) actually just says "nevertheless," and I'm not personally familiar with a situation when you could justifiably use one but not the other.

According to merriam-webster.com's Learner's Dictionary, they have the same definition as well:

> in spite of what has just been said

…although [nonetheless](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/nonetheless) is marked as *somewhat formal*, while [nevertheless](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/nevertheless) is not.

Answer (score 65):

***Nonetheless*** is used when talking about an *amount* of something.

> He really botched it tonight.  I love him nonetheless.

Here we are saying that the amount I love him has not been diminished from the level I loved him prior to his having botched it.

***Nevertheless*** should be used when talking about doing something despite the facts.

> It could be dangerous. Nevertheless, I've got to try.

Here we are saying that I will try despite the fact that it could be dangerous.

Note though that quite often interchanging the words results in a sentence with a different nuance of meaning but the same overall outcome.

Switching to *nevertheless* in my first example changes the meaning from *I don't love him any less* to *I love him despite the facts* - very similar but not quite the same.

And this is why interchanging them works so often. Because usually when saying that the amount that I do something has not diminished in any way it is because something has occurred that had the possibility of diminishing it and in not diminishing the amount I have essentially done that despite the facts.

Comment: I don't find the slightest hint of the distinction you are making, in my understanding of the sentences. Perhaps it's a dialect thing.

Comment: I kind of see where you are coming from here. You are proposing that "I love him nonetheless" means essentially "The amount less that I love him is none." (Now there is an ugly sentence.) I'm not convinced, though. Can you expand a little?

Comment: @ColinFine: [Here is an example](http://books.google.com/books?id=KQcNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22nonetheless+for+it%22&dq=%22nonetheless+for+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZorkT97zA8fd0QGhmezMCQ&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCA) where I think the meaning is clear: "*Julius II loved him nonetheless for it...*" means *Julius didn't love him any less because of it.*

Comment: @Jim. Ah. I see the problem. That is not the **word** _nonetheless_: it is the **phrase** _none the less_. To see the difference, consider _Julius did not love him any the less_. There is no **word** _anytheless_.

Comment: To put Jim's point slightly differently, _nonetheless_ means 'not the slightest bit less' while _nevertheless_ means 'despite that'.

Comment: @HStephenStraight No, _nonetheless_ does not mean ‘not the slightest bit less’. It means exactly the same as _nevertheless_. What does mean ‘not the slightest bit less’ is ***none the less***, three words. The first part of this answer is quite simply wrong.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Point well taken. I concede.

Comment: @Jim. Is this your opinion or can you provide references to this distinction?

Answer (score 25):

***The Age of ‘Nevertheless’***

Historically, the most striking difference between *nevertheless* and *nonetheless* is how much older *nevertheless* is. Samuel Johnson includes it in his original *Dictionary of the English Language* (1756):

> NEVERTHELESS. *ad*. [*never the less*.] Notwithstanding that. *Bacon*.

That last notation means that Johnson found an instance of the word in Francis Bacon’s works; Bacon died in 1626. And it appears in Google Books search results going at least as far back as [*Injunctions Given by the Queens Majesty, Concerning Both the Clergy and the Laity of this Realm*](http://books.google.com/books?id=SvBYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22nevertheless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q_YoVKa8EIjIiwKo2oDQCQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22nevertheless%22&f=false) (1559):

> 21. Also, For as much as variance and contention is a thing that most displeaseth God, and is most contrary to the blessed Communion of the body and blood of our Saviour Christ, Curates shall in no wise admit to the receiving thereof any of their cure and flock, which be openly known to live in sin without repentance, or hath maliciously and openly contended with his Neighbor, unless the same do first charitably and openly reconcile himself again, remitting all rancor and malice, whatsoever controversie hath been between them. And **nevertheless**, the just titles and rights they may charitably prosecute before such as have authority to hear the same.
>
> …
>
> 23. Also, That they shall take away, utterly extinct and destroy all Shrines, coverings of Shrines, all Tables, Candlesticks, Trindals, and Rolls of Wax, Pictures, Paintings, and all other Monuments of feigned Miracles, Pilgrimages, Idolatry an Superstition, so that there remain no memory of the same in walls, glass-windows, or elsewhere within their Churches and Houses, preserving **nevertheless**, or repairing both the walls and glass-windows ; and they shall exhort all their Parishioners to do the like, within their several Houses.

---

***The Youth of ‘Nonetheless’***

But Johnson does not have an entry for *nonetheless*—and neither do the various Webster’s dictionaries published between 1806 and 1960. In fact, the first *Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary* to include an entry for *nonetheless* is the Seventh Edition (1963), with the briefest of definitions:

> **nonetheless**  *adv* : NEVERTHELESS

That’s not to say that the phrase “none the less” does not long predate the twentieth century. A Google Books search for “none the less” turns up matches from the early 1700s, such as this example from [*A Review of the Affairs of France*](http://books.google.com/books?id=El8TAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22none+the+less%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uvcoVM77D8PCigL3tIH4DQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22none%20the%20less%22&f=false) (March 13, 1705):

> First, This Gentleman begs the Question, That there being so much Yarn Spun in *Yorkshire*, there is **none the less** Spun anywhere else.
>
> And so many Stuffs made in *London*, there is **none the less** made in *Norwich*.

And many later matches are structured along similar lines, like this one from [*The National Preacher*](http://books.google.com/books?id=0yUPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA321&dq=%22none+the+less%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uvcoVM77D8PCigL3tIH4DQ&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22none%20the%20less%22&f=false) (February 1832):

> Man sustains two relations to God. He is a moral agent, that is, susceptible of obligations, and he is dependant on God for sanctifying impressions. In the former relation he is active, in the latter he is passive. These two relations are almost entirely independent of each other. That is to say, we are **none the less** dependant for being under obligations ; and on the other hand, we are **none the less** bound to believe because faith is " the gift of God," and **none the less** bound to love because love is " the fruit of the Spirit.”

And this one from George Aiton, “[The Purpose of English in the High School](http://books.google.com/books?id=0qBZAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA164&dq=%22none+the+less%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CfsoVLueKI_oiwKPtICADQ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22none%20the%20less%22&f=false)” (read November 1896, and reprinted from *School Review* 1897):

> A bowlder is **none the less** granitic because gray lichens fleck its sides. Gibraltar is **none the less** a fortress because wild vines festoon its precipices. Longfellow is **none the less** great because blue-eyed banditti trampled over his dignity. The human heart is **none the less** true to stern and difficult duty because a little of the beauty and of the pleasure of life has crept into it.

And this one from Max Lerner, [*Ideas Are Weapons: The History and Uses of Ideas*](http://books.google.com/books?id=c5Lhmmt06gsC&pg=PA425&dq=%22none+the+less%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Uv4oVImVFKSLjALImoGACA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22none%20the%20less%22&f=false) (1939):

> It is no historical accident but a matter of cultural logic that a Field should grow where a Morgan does; and a Brandeis is **none the less** organic a product of capitalist society than is a Debs. If the contrast between the first pair and the second is precipitous it is **none the less** contrast and not contradiction.

In each of these instances, “none the less” does not mean “nevertheless”; it means “not any less.” In the Lerner quotation, however, you can see how the second instance of “none the less” might be taken to mean “nevertheless,” whereas the first instance of “none the less” simply could not be understood that way. This seems to be what occurred with the one-word form *nonetheless* when it emerged in the first half of the twentieth century. For example, from Noel Busch, “[Donald Nelson](http://books.google.com/books?id=400EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22nonetheless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8v8oVOXiDOPHiwLn2ICgCA&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22nonetheless%22&f=false),” in *Life* magazine (July 6, 1942):

> During the years when Nelson was practicing it as diligently as possible, U. S. business was undergoing a most extraordinary experience. Since, in effect, business is the U. S., efforts to belittle it patently constitute a sort of treason. **Nonetheless**, shortly after the last war apparently animated by an involved kind of masochism, U. S. intellectuals began not only to belittle but to berate, bedevil and belabor business by every means that came to mind. … Fundamentally, the question of whether U.S. business is good or bad is about as realistic as the question of whether U.S. air is good or bad. **Nonetheless**, by 1932 precisely this question had become the chief issue in a presidential campaign.

---

***Changes in Frequency Over Time***

An Ngram chart for the years 1800 through 2005 for the terms “nevertheless” (the red line), “never the less” (the yellow line), “nonetheless” (the blue line), and “none the less” (the green line) shows how the frequency of “none the less” has dropped in the past 80 years as the frequency of “nonetheless” has risen:

[image]

In addition, the frequency of “nevertheless” has taken a hit during the same time period, which suggests that in some of instances where people might have used *nevertheless* in the past, they may now be using *nonetheless* instead. If so, this state of affairs may provide another indication that the two terms now mean virtually the same thing.

Answer (score 19):

Semantically, as others have said, there is no real difference between *nonetheless* and *nevertheless*.

There is a difference (or at least a tendency towards a difference) in syntax, though: their locations tend to differ when used as phrasal adverbs.

*Nevertheless* is usually placed **before** the clause it comments on, while *nonetheless* tends to feel slightly more awkward in this position (though by no means impossible).

> I will defer to your judgment. Nevertheless, I still think we ought to tell her.
>   I will defer to your judgment. (?)Nonetheless, I still think we ought to tell her.

Conversely, *nonetheless* when used as a phrasal adverb is most commonly placed **after** the clause it refers to, where *nevertheless* can feel downright stilted:

> I will defer to your judgment, but I still think we ought to tell her nonetheless.
>   I will defer to your judgment, but I still think we ought to tell her (?)nevertheless.

Neither of these two is more than a somewhat vague tendency; exceptions are plenty and quite common. The tendency makes for a good rule of thumb, though.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is a subtle one, and the two can frequently (typically?) be used interchangeably. But what difference there is between these two compound words is rooted in the single components that make them different: never, and none.

"Never" is concerned with time, and so is more directly applicable in connection with an event or something that can happen: "It's cold today, but I am going out nevertheless." There's been no change in the likelihood of a given thing happening.

"None" is concerned with quantity, and so is more directly applicable in connection with a measurable quality, attribute, condition, degree, etc: "It's not as cold today, but it is cold nonetheless." There's been a change, but the change is being discounted, and so the given situation or condition remains the same.

Even in those examples, the two can be reasonably swapped. But, in imagining a context where those two sentences might be used, there's a shift in tone or emphasis related to an intention to go out; or an assessment of how much intention there is to do something (go out) that is not given in the sentence itself, but that in context is or will be understood -- nonetheless, or nevertheless, or despite that, or without consideration of that.

Answer (score 0):

This site differentiates **nonetheles**, **nevertheless** and **notwithstanding** to boot: https://blogs.transparent.com/english/nonetheless-nevertheless-notwithstanding/

The main difference, as cited in other answers, is that never concerns time, none concerns quantity and notwithstanding means "in spite of", "despite".

"Compare the words none the less with never the less. If used as a pronoun, none means not one, no one, or not any. Applied as an adverb, it means not at all. In either case, the word signifies a physical or metaphysical thing. Never is an adverb which negates time. Viewed this way, one can see a difference.

```
“I kept losing money until I was left with none.”
“I never believed that I would lose all my money.”
```

Now, take it a step further and add to the sentences above.

```
“I kept losing money until I was left with none. The excitement was worth it, nonetheless.”
“I never believed that I would lose all my money. Nevertheless, I continued to play.”
```

"

Comment: Nicole has already given the subtle connotations connected with the composition of the lexemes, and this sounds closer to the etymological fallacy (origin determines present usage). But with your examples, apart from distribution (where words may be placed in sentences), the terms could be interchanged.

Answer (score -1):

I have probably used nevertheless and nonetheless interchangeably because I've never been told that there could be a difference in usage, and I've never come across usage where one is preferred over the other.

It may be the case that current usage makes no distinction but a distinction can be made, just as Nicole and Jim tried.

Firstly, surely the origin of the two words are from the conjoining of the obvious words that are their constituents, and, notwithstanding supposed current usage, the conjoined words were to mean the same as the words separated into a phrase.

Thus, nevertheless was to mean never the less; and nonetheless was to mean none the less. In both of these phrases the common and primary word is less; hence we are referring to the measure of something.

With never we are referring to all instances, past, present, and future; with none we are only referring to the instance in question.

Answer (score -2):

I think in analyzing the two words *nonetheless* and *nevertheless*, we should separate the different parts and ask what the meanings of *never* and *none* are.

- *None* means “nothing” or “the absence of”.
- *Never* means “impossible”.

So I ask you, is the distinction between *never* and *none* clear?

Comment: if that's clear, then why does the OP need to ask?

Comment: @Jaytee, ideal answers are researched and include references. Moreover, the meaning of compound word is sometimes unrelated to the meaning of its components.